# Set File Permissions in C#

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I wanna set the permissions on a file to "can not be deleted" in C#, only readable. But I don't know how to do this. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [File.SetAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx).  There are lots of examples online about how to use it.

Taken from that MSDN page:

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

        if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
        {
            // Show the file.
            attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.Hidden);
            File.SetAttributes(path, attributes);
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is no longer hidden.", path);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Hide the file.
            File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is now hidden.", path);
        }
```

Comment: I think the question is about "permissions" not "attributes"...

Answer (score 15):

Is this about attributes (see jb.'s answer) or permissions, i.e. read/write access, etc.? In the latter case see [File.SetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8).

From the MSDN:

```
// Get a FileSecurity object that represents the
// current security settings.
FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType));

// Set the new access settings.
File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
```

See [How to grant full permission to a file created by my application for ALL users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108399/how-to-grant-full-permission-to-a-file-created-by-my-application-for-all-users#16216587) for a more concrete example.

In the original question it sounds like you want to disallow the `FileSystemRights.Delete` right.

Comment: the code is also in this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The link above (File.AccessControl) is the German language version.  The English version is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8 for those who answer 'Nein.' to Sprichst du Deutsch'

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to copy in the RemoveAttribute method, which is:

```
    private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
    {
        return attributes & ~attributesToRemove;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that should work on .NET Core:

```
FileSystemAccessRule rule = new (account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
new FileInfo(filePath).GetAccessControl().AddAccessRule(rule);
```