# .NET - Issue trying to figure out if user is running ADMIN or not

Tags: .net, vb.net, admin, uac

I am trying to figure out how to determine if a program is running admin mode. I have shown some example coding on what I am using below in .NET:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim pr = New WindowsPrincipal(id)
        Dim isAdm As Boolean = pr.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)

        If isAdm = True Then
             MessageBox.Show(Me, "Running Admin")
        else
             MessageBox.Show(Me, "Not Running Admin")    
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

This works great for the most case but I have a user who is running Windows 7 Professional and it is returning TRUE no matter what if he ran as admin or not.

I don't know what would cause this, but is there a way to figure out why this is happening, and possibly a solution. Either to figure out that the program will always return true regardless through coding, or maybe a solution to the coding for this issue.

Any clues?

Comment: Your code is checking whether _the current **user**_ is admin, not whether _the current **process**_ is running with admin privileges. To check if a process runs with elevated (admin) privileges, you will most likely have to deal with tokens. [**This answer might be helpful**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4497572/3740093).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried that too and it also wasn't working. It also returns true which is really odd. The problem overall is that if a user first runs the program as admin, the files get written with admin rights too. Then if you launch the program as a user, the files cannot be written because and give an ACCESS DENIED. I was trying to think how I can prevent this, or at least warn the user.

Comment: Could you just set file permissions to `everyone` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108399/how-to-grant-full-permission-to-a-file-created-by-my-application-for-all-users

Comment: How would that work? Would I have to call it every time a new file is created? I get it works on a folder, but if my program generates files on the go (mapper tool for instance that creates a file here and there) then do I have to keep granting permissions?

Comment: Nevermind, tested it out, it works great now! I set it for users instead of everyone, but overall, good stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the .NET way; but i can give you the native code, which you can then P/Invoke call into:

```
/*
    This function returns true if you are currently running with admin privileges.
    In Vista and later, if you are non-elevated, this function will 
    return false (you are not running with administrative privileges).
    If you *are* running elevated, then IsUserAdmin will return true, 
    as you are running with admin privileges.

    Windows provides this similar function in Shell32.IsUserAnAdmin. 
    But that function is depricated. 
    This code is adapted from from the docs for CheckTokenMembership:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389.aspx

    Note: 
       - you can be an administrator and not have admin privileges 
         (function returns false)
       - you can have admin privileges even though you're not an administrator 
         (function returns true)

    Any code released into the public domain. No attribution required.
*/

Boolean IsUserAdmin()
{
   Boolean isAdmin;

   PSID administratorsGroup = StringToSid("S-1-5-32-544"); //well-known sid

   if (!CheckTokenMembership(0, administratorsGroup, out isAdmin)
      isAdmin = false;

   FreeSid(administratorsGroup);

   return isAdmin;
}
```

**Note**: Using CheckTokenMembership against the admins group is very different than other code floating around out there. The other code:

- uses `OpenProcessToken` to get the *"me"* token
- uses `GetTokenInformation` and `TokenGroups` to get `TOKEN_GROUPS`, which lists all groups the user is a member of
- iterates the returned groups, using `EqualSid` to compare them with the Adminstrators SID

This is wrong because:

> You can be a member of the administrators group, but not have administrator privelages!

This code can be useful useful to know if you *could* elevate; whereas IsUserAdmin tells you if you *are* elevated.

Similarly, you can have administrator rights, but not be a member of the administrators group. Use `IsUserAdmin()` to see if you currently *actually* have administrative rights.