# OnAfterInstall not working after installation winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, file-permissions

I'm new to winform programming and trying to generating exe setup file, for that I'm using [MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects).

I've created .exe file and it's working fine, but after installation every time I need to go the installation directory and give permission to the user.
To get rid out from this issue, I've tried to use [`AfterInstall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.afterinstall.aspx) event and give all permission to user.

```
public partial class ClientInstaller: Installer
{
   public ClientInstaller() : base()
   {
       AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(AfterInstallEventHandler);
   }
}

private void AfterInstallEventHandler()
{       
    string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);

    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appPath);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

But seems like event not fired after installation. Then I tried to override `OnAfterInstall`

```
public partial class ClientInstaller: Installer
{
   protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
   {
       base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
       // Add steps to be done after the installation is over.
       Console.WriteLine("OnAfterInstall method of MyInstaller called");
   }
}
```

Though it's not showing me console(changed target to console).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: For answers see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108399/1845672