# Is there an equivalent of C#´s | operator in VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pipe, operator-keyword, equivalent

Is there an equivalent of the C#'s pipe operator (|) in VB.Net?

I have some code from here [How to grant full permission to a file created by my application for ALL users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108399/how-to-grant-full-permission-to-a-file-created-by-my-application-for-all-users)

It is in C# and i want to convert it to VB.Net. I am at this point so far (VS says there is an error: | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit):

```
Sub ZugriffsrechteEinstellen()

    Dim dInfo As New DirectoryInfo(strPfadSpracheINI)
    Dim dSecurity As New DirectorySecurity

    dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl()
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow))

    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity)

End Sub
```

Comment: The VB equivalent is `Or`.  `Or` will do a bitwise OR of two integral values.  And, like C#'s `|`, it will do a non-short-cutting OR operation between two Booleans.  And, to be complete, the VB equivalent of C#'s short-cutting OR (`||`) is `OrElse`

Comment: [Or Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator).

Comment: Type into Google “c# to vb converter”

Comment: Why the downvotes, the question seems perfectly legit to me...

Comment: @Meta-Knight if I was a betting guy I would say because it's already been answered before here on SO in one form or another, a quick Google search will show exactly the OP what is is etc...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Not that easy to find relevant results by searching for special characters (`|`) or  common words (`Or`) in Google, also if it's a duplicate it should be simply closed as duplicate ;-) I couldn't find a duplicate question with a quick search altough I'm sure there is one too.

Comment: @Meta-Knight true, but then again you shouldn't just be putting in just that character, you'll get a lot of miss-leads `Is there an equivalent C# pipe in VB.Net?` seems to be more of a question that would have better hits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent is [`Or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator).

```
InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit
```

It will perform bitwise "or" operation between operands.

For example if you have the following enumeration

C#:

```
enum Values
{
    None = 0,
    Odd = 1,
    Even = 2,
    All = 3
}
```

VB:

```
Enum Values
    None = 0
    Odd = 1
    Even = 2
    All = 3
End Enum
```

The result of `Values.Odd | Values.Even` (`Values.Odd Or Values.Even`) is `Values.All`. This is because `Odd = 1`  is `01` in binary representation and `Even = 2` is `10` and `01 or 10` equals `11` which is `3 (All)`.

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer to include specifics as what `Or` does, this would back your answer with more useful information.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Updated my answer.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, this helps other that may come across this answer to help them.